# Yapsy minimal example

Tags: python, plugins

Can anyone provide a minimal working example using the [Yapsy plugin framework](http://yapsy.sourceforge.net)?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here's a very simple example.  It has three files:

- plugins\plugin1.py - the plugin.  This has to contain a class inherited from IPlugin.
- plugins\plugin1.yapsy-plugin - information about the plugin.
- yapsy-example.py - the main script.  This just loads all the plugins it can find in the "plugins" directory, and calls a method on them to prove that they work.

You could add more plugins to the plugins directory, and this script would loop around them all.

There's another more complicated example at [http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/weblog/posts/BB923.html (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20130731202108/http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/weblog/posts/BB923.html).

**yapsy-example.py**

```
from yapsy.PluginManager import PluginManager

def main():   
    # Load the plugins from the plugin directory.
    manager = PluginManager()
    manager.setPluginPlaces(["plugins"])
    manager.collectPlugins()

    # Loop round the plugins and print their names.
    for plugin in manager.getAllPlugins():
        plugin.plugin_object.print_name()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**plugins\plugin1.py**

```
from yapsy.IPlugin import IPlugin

class PluginOne(IPlugin):
    def print_name(self):
        print "This is plugin 1"
```

**plugins\plugin1.yapsy-plugin**

```
[Core]
Name = Plugin 1
Module = plugin1

[Documentation]
Author = John Smith
Version = 0.1
Website = http://lotsofplugins.com
Description = My first plugin
```

Comment: Hmmm, that suggests that your plugins aren't being found.  Are they in the plugins\ subdirectory of the directory that contains yapsy-example.py? Are you running yapsy-example.py from that directory?

Comment: One other thing to try - turn on debug logging by adding the following to yapsy-example.py (after the other imports):

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

That should give you some output, which will be helpful for debugging this.

Comment: I realized I was missing the ``from yapsy.IPlugin import IPlugin`` line

Comment: thanks for this nice example.  I found a nice tutorial with small example codes here: [link](http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/weblog/posts/BB923.html)

Comment: This answer is outdated, but still quite helpful.

Comment: @Sepero how is the answer outdated? Have there been changes in yapsy since it was made?

Comment: I don't see mention in this answer of [`activatePluginByName`](http://pythonhosted.org/Yapsy/PluginManager.html#yapsy.PluginManager.PluginManager.activatePluginByName) which is present in the [yapsy Getting Started docs](http://pythonhosted.org/Yapsy/index.html?highlight=activatepluginbyname#id3). Is `activatePluginByName` optional or just missing from this answer?

Comment: `activatePluginByName` just calls the method `activate` for the plugin object, which by default does nothing.