# howto instantiate certain class from string in python project packed by pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

i am using getattr, but i cant make it working with pyinstaller

short summary:

- Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:49:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
- i have project, packed by pyinstaller to single file
- i have external text file with script (Subs.py)

my project cant instantiate class Subs in Subs.py ..

before i pack project by pyinstaller, i can create instance of Subs from Subs.py..
can you please advise, whats wrong on example below ?

in order to show my problem, i prepared very simple example.

`folder structure:
  root-                #folder
      -to              #folder 
         -__init__.py  #file
         -Subs.py      #file
      -main.py         #file`

main.py:

```
import importlib

MyClass = getattr(importlib.import_module("to.Subs"), "Subs")
instance = MyClass()
instance.test()
```

Subs.py:

```
class Subs():
    def test(self):
        print("test")
```

at this moment, execution return as expected:

```
python main.py
test
```

but if i pack project with pyinstaller ( latest installed via pip )
pyinstaller main.py -F 
then i am moving main.exe to root and executing:

```
main.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    MyClass = getattr(importlib.import_module("to.Subs"), "Subs")
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'to'
Failed to execute script main
```

any idea, what i am missing/doing wrogly ? ?

Comment: I don't know pyinstaller myself, but what is the "single file" it produced named, and where is it located relative to the folders you've shown?

Comment: pyinstaller command ( which is in text) will generate binary main.exe (i am on windows)... then i am placing this main.exe to root ( same level as main.py)

Comment: i assume it is some problem with lib path, but i cant figure it out...

Comment: Try adding Subs.py as a hidden import in pyinstaller. https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports

Comment: i think i confused you .. sory.    name Subs.py is just example... i need to be able to import& instantiate  class with another names...    so i think i cant use hidden import, as i cant spefify exacly what module it will be. i know only location ( path ) .....

Comment: You are right. Simply using --hidden-import=Subs won't work. You have to use it with the [-p DIR](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search) option and point to the folder that includes your modules. If that fails, you can also try to bundle the files as [additional data](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle).

Comment: i was able to do this with your help Repiklis... than you alot. Subs got loaded.Unfortunately Subs was only example  i cant do this with random name, as i dont know in advance, what class will be in folder.   i cancel idea to make it as in question, and i decided to use python module yapsy... here is minimal example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333128/yapsy-minimal-example    example works with pyinstaller, and thats what i want .   so at this moment i will leave question as answered by Repiklis, but i am choosing another aproache. yapsy & pyinstaller works well. thx all for commenting.

Comment: ehm, how to mark Repiklis as correct answer to question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You are right. Simply using --hidden-import=Subs won't work. You have to use it with the -p DIR option and point to the folder that includes your modules. If that fails, you can also try to bundle the files as additional data. –  Aug 8 at 14:31
"
i am marking this as answer, as i could successfuly instan.class by using --hidden-import & -b...

credit goes to ->Repiklis